# Empty characters in C/ C++

Tags: c++, c

Are there any empty characters available in C or C++? And by empty character I mean, no white-space, no null character, just to skip that place of the particular character. I don't want to replace that character with the above mentioned ones, but to just disappear that character and it's place.

For example, I have a string s = "thisIsAma@zing$"
and I want to skip those '@' and '$' without creating another string or utilising more space, so is there any way to do that? If so, then please tell.

Thank You

Comment: What do you mean by disappearing and skipping characters?

Comment: What is it that you want to do with the string its unclear, Do you want to remove all characters other than the alphabet?

Comment: **U+200B**, Unicode zero-width space could be used. Requires wide characters. But can you not shift all characters and fill NULs after the end?

Comment: Picture standing at the tail end of a queue. While you wait, some impatient or harried people abandon the queue (like your special characters leaving the string.) What happens? Do those 'holes' stay as 'holes' in the queue? Write some code and figure out this problem for yourself. You will be proud of your achievement! (You're welcome, btw...)

Comment: Most of the ASCII [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character) (0 to 31) are unused in today's computers. For example 0x01 or 0x02 can be used as placeholders, as there is nearly no risk of collision with real text.

Comment: @prapin Great... Next week SO will have a question, "Why does strstr() not find 'Amazing' in this string that (see JPG) printf shows is _really_ there.??" and "Why does strlen() say 16 when this string is obviously 14 chars long???" Shouldn't encourage 'clever but misguided' solution seeking...

Comment: @prapin Nothing of what you said is true. ASCII control characters  0-31 as well as 127 and 255 ARE STILL recognized as control characters by most i/o streams implementations, including terminal, text file i/o, etc. on many systems. Standard wasn't abandoned, it was adopted into international. Also 0-31 characters are considered whitespace and must be treated as such by implementations,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual charset in use is not defined by the C++ standard itself, but by the particular implementation. That being said, I'm not aware of anything like that in common text encodings, and ultimately it's not clear how would that work: say that × was such a character: `thisIsAma×zing$` and `thisIsAmazing$` would still be two different character sequences, even if onscreen rendering would be the same, meaning that they would not *really* be the same.

Anyhow, in an `std::string` you don't have to create a new one to remove unwanted characters: `std::string` is modifiable, and algorithms such as `std::remove_if` works inplace and without reallocing.

Comment: Now that you mention it, your guess of `std::remove_if` is probably what the OP wanted.